# Changing Existing Add, Remove and Move same row on all sheets to batching version

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google sheet that acts as a hub for data on our pupils. I have made macros for removing, moving or adding pupils to this as they are located in the same row across multiple tabs. Loops are now timing out.

I have looked into it and apparently changing it to batching would make it more efficient. I have had a couple of attempts at changing it but no luck .

\ Add Pupil Code

```
function insertRow() {
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheets[i].insertRowBefore(row);

  }
}
```

\ Remove Pupil Code

```
function deleteRow() {
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheets[i].deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

\ Move Pupil Code

```
function moveRow() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var formResponse = ui.prompt('Move Pupil Row', 'Enter the pupils new form', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
var currentResponse = ui.prompt('Move Pupil Row', 'Enter the current row number for this pupil', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
var newResponse = ui.prompt('Move Pupil Row', 'Enter the new row number for this pupil', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

if (newResponse.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
Logger.log('Collected New Form', formResponse.getResponseText());

Logger.log('Collected Current Row', currentResponse.getResponseText());

Logger.log('Collected New Row', newResponse.getResponseText());

var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
var row = currentResponse.getResponseText()

var newForm = formResponse.getResponseText()
var pupilData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('PupilData');
var formCell = pupilData.getRange("A"+row); 
formCell.setValue(newForm);

var newRow = newResponse.getResponseText()
var newRowRange = "A"+newRow+":AP"+newRow

if (row < newRow) {
  var rowRange = "A"+row+":AP"+row
} else {
  row = +row
  row = row + 1
  var rowRange = "A"+row+":AP"+row
}

for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  sheets[i].insertRowBefore(newRow);    
}


for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  sheets[i].getRange(rowRange).moveTo(sheets[i].getRange(newRowRange));
  sheets[i].deleteRow(row);
} 

var halfTerm1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('HT1');
var halfTerm2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('HT2');
var halfTerm3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('HT3');
var halfTerm4 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('HT4');
var halfTerm5 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('HT5');
var halfTerm6 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('HT6');
var year = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Year');
halfTerm1.getRange('C5:AP').clearContent();
halfTerm2.getRange('C5:AP').clearContent();
halfTerm3.getRange('C5:AP').clearContent();
halfTerm4.getRange('C5:AP').clearContent();
halfTerm5.getRange('C5:AP').clearContent();
halfTerm6.getRange('C5:AP').clearContent();
year.getRange('C5:AP').clearContent();



} else if (newResponse.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
Logger.log('The user canceled the dialog.');



} else {
    Logger.log('The user closed the dialog.');



}
}
```

The code above works, just it times out now that the google sheet has a years worth of data in and needs to be more efficient, especially the move pupil code.

Comment: Could you show the execution log so that we can see what's taking so much time? It can be found in `View > Execution log`...

Comment: @ross it manages to run on my home computer so below is the execution log for a successful run. At work the computers can't handle it and that why I was hoping to make it more efficient. I will run it in work tomorrow id you want that copy.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JGWcjIYhf_louBon6Yh1-L470t41k-ChEwPQWMc7Kmg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So you have a bunch of empty rows on most of the tabs to save a spot for the pupil?

Comment: This is a little broad for SO.  What exactly are you looking for a full refactor of your code or suggestions to improve efficiency,  I think this question is better suited for codereview.stackexchange

Comment: Can you give more info about the sheets?  You are spending 50% of your execution time, about 5 minutes, on just the first loop of `insertRowBefore`.  I am trying to replicate that on 50 sheets and filling them up with numbers and calling `insertRowBefore` and I haven't gone over 30 seconds yet.  Maybe the Sheet has some bells and whistles on it that is slowing down `insertRowBefore`?  Can you describe the make up of the rows (data types, etc) so we can try to replicate your slow execution time?

Comment: @dwmorrin the google sheet this is on acts as a sort of "back-end" for the records of a behaviour system at a school. I build multiple google sheets that link to this one that pull the data. Each week the behaviour records are put in this main sheet and then formulas total up the rest. The macros are for when a pupil is added, removed or a new one starts to make sure the data stays in line with the pupil. Here is a link to a copy of it without pupil names. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LCFoPGE9XrHrs2LkjTxKs0kh5az2PdAPsjuaHXL56nY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to make the requests using the Sheets API [1] with the UrlFetchApp class [2], this way you could initiate the requests without needing to wait for the response from the previous request.

I implemented the fetchAll() method [2] with two requests to delete some columns and rows, here is the code (you need to put the sheetID):

```
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/SHEET_ID:batchUpdate";

var requestBody = {
  "requests": [
    {
      "deleteDimension": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "ROWS",
          "startIndex": 0,
          "endIndex": 3
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "deleteDimension": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "COLUMNS",
          "startIndex": 1,
          "endIndex": 4
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

var request1 = {
  'url': url,
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
  },
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(requestBody),
  'muteHttpExceptions': true
};

var requests = [request1]
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);

Logger.log(response)
```

I used the example request json from the "Delete rows or columns" part [3].

To add more requests, you can either add more request jsons in the fetchAll() array parameter or add more update chart jsons in the 'requests' array on requestBody.

[1] https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object)

[3] https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn

Answer (score 0):

The slow down is your `ARRAYFORMULA` cells.
Once you remove the `ARRAYFORMULA` calls, the `insertRowBefore` execution drops from 5 minutes to 30 seconds.

*(For the sake of readers who did not examine the linked spreadsheet: This particular spreadsheet is 50 sheets deep, 42 columns wide, and 1500 rows long, with `ARRAYFORMULA` calls on each sheet.)*

During all those seconds that each sheet spends on the `insertRowBefore` loop the sheet is having to deal with calculating `ARRAYFORMULA`.  You'll need to rethink how this system is working.  Can you separate the data entry from the data reporting?   Maybe have another spreadsheet that imports this one and does the calculating, while this one just stores plain data without any embedded formulas.